# rank function with limits in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, limit, rank

select * from rankings;

```
 students | stu_id | card_id
----------+--------+---------
 Charlie  |     11 |       1
 Shakira  |     22 |       2
 Selena   |     33 |       3
 Ross     |     44 |       4
 Chandler |     55 |       5
 James    |     66 |       6
 Kylie    |     77 |       7
```

Here is the table kindly tell me how we can apply the rank function in it with Postgresql?

Comment: What is the output you want here?

Comment: what's the ranking based on ? how do you rank the students?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: please share the code you have tried on this.